# How to override the "new tab" page of browser with a specific URL using Crossrider APIs?

Tags: javascript, browser, add-on, crossrider

How to override the "new tab" page of browser with a specific URL using Crossrider APIs?

In [Chrome](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples.html#chrome_url_overrides) and other browsers, you can override the "new tab" page with a specific URL [i.e. http://www.mysiteurl.com/]. How can you implement this using [Crossrider APIs](http://crossrider.com/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently, the Crossrider API does not support this feature but we will consider adding an API to approximate this behavior for all supported browsers.

[**Disclaimer**: I am a Crossrider employee]

Comment: @NeelKamal The product team considered the feature and for now it is not being implemented. It's inclusion will be considered again at some point but is unlikely to be in the foreseeable future.